# how to send response with resque

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

We have 3 resque workers here, that process and convert some data. Now, I need to send a response to the one who sent me the data. How do I send a response? Do resque have async-something way to send a response to a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resque can't (and was never designed to) do that, however, you can use redis or your database as a communication mechanism.  We actually do this as we process long-running tasks.  For example, just create a new key in redis when enqueueing the job, passing that key in with the job arguments.  As the job processes, it may update that key in redis.  Whoever enqueued that job simply needs to watch that redis key for changes.

There are more efficient "push" type solutions too (such as HTTP notifications to a controller in your app, or sockets), if polling is a problem, though with only 3 workers it doesn't sound like it should be.

Comment: oh, too bad. But i think that 'push' will fit better for our architecture. thanks a lot